# (Python) Why is this index out of range?

Tags: python, list, range, out

The following code is what I have written to read data from a website and store it in a list. The code works, but it also throws a list out of range error regardless. Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
import urllib.request

data_url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"
aboveFifty = 0
belowFifty = 0

""" The variables for storage """
age = 0
worksFor = ""
college = ""
salary = ""
bools = True

try:
    print("Retrieving the data... ")
    local_file, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(data_url)
    print("Data retrieved")
    fh = open(local_file, "r")
    print("Reading the file... ")

    for row in fh:
        table = [row.strip().split(" ")]
        salary = table[0][14]

        if bools == True:
            print("Table: ", table)
            bools = False

        if salary == "<=50K":
            belowFifty += 1
        elif salary == ">50K":
            aboveFifty += 1

except IOError as e:
    print("IO Error: ", e)
except IndexError as ie:
    print("Index error: ", ie)

print("Above fifty: ", aboveFifty, "Below fifty: ", belowFifty)
fh.close()
```

The traceback error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Killian\workspace\College\Assignment.py", line 25, in <module>
    salary = table[0][14]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Please do include the traceback of any errors you see. Now you are leaving us to guess *where* the exception happens.

Comment: Moreover, your indentation, as it stands, is incorrect and leads to syntax errors. The code is not runnable, so we can not easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: A common reason why people hit this problem is that they forget Python's indexes start at 0...

Comment: attempted to fix your formatting to something sensible.

Comment: *Aside*: The brackets around `.split()` are confusing and unnecessary. Prefer: `table = row.strip().split(" ")`, `salary = table[14]`. Well, actually prefer the `csv` module which makes this all much easier.

Comment: Ignore the terrible indentation, I can provide a link to pastebin if you wish. I had trouble getting all of the code within the code tags so I had to improvise. I can assure you that the code can be run.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is corrupt. Specifically, there is a blank line at the end of your data file. You can work with the corrupt data like so:

```
for row in fh:
    table = [row.strip().split(" ")]
    if not table:
        continue    # <-- ignore blank lines
    salary = table[0][14]
```